# How to add custom metadata to AWS presigned_url method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, metadata, md5, pre-signed-url

I have the following code using presigned_url:

```rb
 def upload_parameters_md5
    put = aws_object.presigned_url(:put,
                                     content_md5: md5_base64,
                                     content_type: mime_type,
                                     cache_control: 'public, max-age=2592000',
                                     metadata: {
                                       fileid: id,
                                     },
                                   )
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      fields: {},
      url: put,
      headers: {
        'content-md5': md5_base64,
        'content-type': mime_type,
        'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',
        'x-amz-meta-fileid': id
      }
    }
end
```

I want to add the custom metadata `fileid` but if i send the request as is i get a `403` error **'There were some headers which were not signed - x-amz-meta-fileid'**. But if i remove `x-amz-meta-fileid` from the header the request goes through successfully.

Is this the correct way to add custom metadata? Will the signature be calculated correctly? And why are there no error when adding the other metadatas `content-md5`, `content-type` etc?

Comment: Only `host` and `x-amz-*` headers are **required** to be signed.